# Mobile Internet issue on Ubuntu bq aquaris

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Somehow theater mobile Internet doesn't work and I don't really have an idea why that could be. The phone shows the APN `dato.bob` in user-defined and I tried to write the APN name and password into user-defined but it all doesn't work.

Comment: There are some bugs concerning the apn-settings. I can't modify the settings. For the provider bob there is the following bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ofono/+bug/1435784 It should be already fixed. But I don't know when the next update will come. In your case there must be a failure in the apn database on the phone.

Comment: Ok thank you. So I'll have to wait for a update that fixes the problem or is there anything else I can do?

Comment: sorry I dont know. Maybe switching to the developer channel helps, because the bug should be already fixed: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/image-channels/ I'm not sure if it is the best thing to do, because the developer chanel seems to be realy unstable. But I didn't try it so if you have time one your side do it :D